# Benefit of applying Unit-of-Work on Service-layer instead of Controller

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, transactions, unit-of-work

When implementing MVC project, I usually add Service Layer to perform the actual work. But actually sometimes 1 Web Request should be done with several AppService methods. Then the location of Unit-of-Work (UoW) may affect the coding handling.

No matter in C# EF/Java Spring, there's Transaction annotation in Service Layer methods, so the transaction is Per-Service based (i.e. UoW on Service layer). Let's take Java version as example here:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
Public class UserAppService{
  public UserDTO createUser() {
      // Do sth to create a new user
      userRepository.save(userBean);

      // Convert userBean to userDTO
      return userDTO;
  }
  public xxx DoSth() {
      // Break the operation here
      throw new Exception("Whatever");

      // (never execute actually)
      sthRepository.save(someBean);
  }
}
```

Then in Controller:

```
Public class SomeController : Controller {
  Public xxx DoSth(){
    UserAppService Service = new UserAppService();
    Service.CreateUser(); // DB committed
    Service.DoSth();      //Exception thrown

  }
}
```

With this structure, If there's any exception thrown on 2nd service method call, the 1st service method still commit the user to the DB. If I want "all-or-nothing" handling, this structure doesn't work unless I wrap those service method calls into another wrapper service call with single transaction. But it's sort of extra work.

Another version is using transaction on Controller action level instead (i.e. UoW on Controller Action). Let's take C# code as example:

*Remarks: AppService in code version 2 here use the DbContext (sth like transaction) defined in controller, and doesn't do any commit inside.*

```
Public class SomeController : Controller {
  Public ActionResult DoSth(){
     using (var DB = new DbContext()){
       Var UserAppService = new UserAppService(DB);
       var userEntity = userAppService.GetUser(userId);
       UserAppService.DoSth(userEntity);

       Var AnotherAppService = new AnotherAppService(DB);
       AnotherAppService.DoSthElse(userEntity);

       // Throw exception here
       throw new Exception("Whatever");

       DB.Save(); // commit
     }
  }
}
```

In this example, there will be no partial commit to the DB.

Is applying UoW on service-layer really better?

Answer (score 2):

> Is applying UoW on service-layer really better?

IMO No.  And you've just figured out why.  If the service methods are discreet and re-usable, they are also not suitable for being atomic transactions.

In .NET the controller should control the transaction lifecycle, and enlist service methods in the transaction.

Note that this *also* implies that the service methods should be local method calls, not remote or web service calls.

Answer (score 1):

It is better because your following the main principle of Object Oriented Programming seperation of concerns.What if you made another controller and wanted to do more database processing using the same object? You dont want to instantiate the controller in which your doing something completely different.By the way check out the facade service pattern http://soapatterns.org/design_patterns/service_facade it may help you understand why its so sexy. [image].Hi the image above shows the pattern, basically you wrap your database access objects with transactional at the service layer so a customerService object can wrap 1,2...inf transactions and either all fail or succeed.

Comment: If UoW on Service pattern is followed, given a common situation that 1 HTTP POST call (i.e. 1 controller action) needs to be done on 2+ service methods with DB changes, how can "partial commit" be prevented in a beautiful way without destructing the UoW on Service pattern?